# What does $\langle A,B\rangle$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

If $G$ is a group and $A,B$ are subgroups of it (or, I guess the definition just needs $A$ and $B$ to be subsets of $G$), what does $\langle A,B\rangle $ mean? I know what $\langle A\rangle $ means (just one set as argument) and I guess that $\langle A,B\rangle =\langle A\cup B\rangle $, but I just want to be sure. If someone can give me a precise definition, it would be very useful for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Your guess is probably right: $\langle A,B \rangle$ is the subgroup generated by $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Further, it wouldn't be unusual to see a mixture of single elements, subsets, subgroups and potentially sets of subsets in the bracket. The meaning is the same, the group generated by all of the 'stuff' in the bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A not uncommon definition of $\langle A, B \rangle$, is simply $\langle A \cup B \rangle$. Another definitions of $\langle A ,B \rangle$ would be $$ \langle A ,B \rangle:= \bigcap_{A,B \subseteq H \in SG} H$$ where $SG$ is the set of subgroups of $G$. Of course these definitions can be extended to any number of sets.

Comment: Thanks! You helped me and didn't leave the question without an answer.